# Why does my chess clock not update the view?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, setinterval

i am trying to see if i can make a chess clock app with multiple players for my gaming group, however im having issues with updating my view when an interval counts down

i dont realy know why it does not work in react native, and any help will be appreciated

my code is down below

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {ScrollView, View, Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import {GlobalStyles} from '../styles/globalStyles';

const TimerScreen = () => {
  const [colors] = useState(["#cbecdf", "#a97272", "#f2a4a4", "#483d8b", "#191970", "#cc66cc", "#cc99cc", "#99cccc", "#ccb399", "#cc9999",
    "#99cc99", "#cc99cc", "#008080", "#800080", "#bada55", "#7193ff", "#ff4500", "#b00b69", "#ff0080", "#ff00ff", "#8000ff", "#0000ff", "#0080ff", 
    "#00ffff", "#00ff80", "#80ff00", "#ffff00", "#ff8000", "#ff0000", "#fd0404", "#ffccff", "#fff0f5", "#bbffff", "#381aaf", "#ff453c", "#cf9066", 
    "#b00b69", "#d3a625",])
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState(
    [{name: "kasper", timeLeft: "1"}, 
    {name: "tatiana", timeLeft: "1"},
    {name: "lars", timeLeft: "1"}]
    );

    const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState(); 

    useEffect(() =>{
      let newPlayers = [...players] 
      for(let player of newPlayers){
        player.timeLeft = `${player.timeLeft}:00`
      }
      setPlayers(newPlayers);
    }, [])


    const startCountDown = (index) =>{
      stopCountDowns();
      countDown(index);
    }

    const stopCountDowns = () => clearInterval(intervalId)

    const countDown = (index) => {
      let newPlayers = [...players];
      let mins = parseInt(newPlayers[index].timeLeft.split(':')[0])
      let secs = parseInt(newPlayers[index].timeLeft.split(':')[1])
      let interval = setInterval(() => {
        console.log("i am running")
        if(secs === 0  && mins !== 0 ){ 
          mins--;
          secs = 60;
        }
        if (secs !== 0){secs--} 
        newPlayers[index].timeLeft = `${mins}:${secs}`
        console.log(newPlayers[index])
        setPlayers(newPlayers)
      }, 1000)
      setIntervalId(interval)
    }

    

  return(
    <ScrollView>
      <View style={GlobalStyles.timerContainer}>
        {players.map((player, index) => 
          <TouchableOpacity style={{width: "50%", height: 150, backgroundColor: colors[index], alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center"}} key={index} onPress={event => startCountDown(index)}>
            <Text>{player.name}</Text>
            <Text>{player.timeLeft}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  )
}

export default TimerScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think the problem with your code was:

- I think you wanted to use a FlatList. FlatList have the extradata prop, which is a state variable that when changes, triggers re-render of the list
- Have your intervalId saved as a ref, so its value would persist through all lifecycles of the component

With that in mind, I made changes to your code.

- I created a state variable, activePlayerIndex and tied an effect to it that starts the timer for the activePlayer.
- To use the extradata prop FlatLists provide, I created a state variable, totalActiveTime that is incremented with all timer ticks.
- For personal preference, I set timeLeft to a number (thats later converted into mm:ss), and added a button for stopping all timers.

Here's the code:

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import {FlatList, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Button} from 'react-native';
// import {GlobalStyles} from '../styles/globalStyles';

const TimerScreen = () => {
  const [colors] = useState(["#cbecdf", "#a97272", "#f2a4a4", "#483d8b", "#191970", "#cc66cc", "#cc99cc", "#99cccc", "#ccb399", "#cc9999",
    "#99cc99", "#cc99cc", "#008080", "#800080", "#bada55", "#7193ff", "#ff4500", "#b00b69", "#ff0080", "#ff00ff", "#8000ff", "#0000ff", "#0080ff", 
    "#00ffff", "#00ff80", "#80ff00", "#ffff00", "#ff8000", "#ff0000", "#fd0404", "#ffccff", "#fff0f5", "#bbffff", "#381aaf", "#ff453c", "#cf9066", 
    "#b00b69", "#d3a625",]);

  const timerLength = 60;
  // I found it easier to work with time in seconds and convert them to mm:ss at render
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState([
    {name: "kasper", timeLeft:timerLength }, 
    {name: "tatiana", timeLeft: timerLength},
    {name: "lars", timeLeft: timerLength}
  ]);
  // variable that states which player is active
  const [activePlayerIndex, setActivePlayerIndex ] = useState(-1)
  // flatlist have a parameter that triggers list updates when the variable change
  const [ totalActiveTime, setTotalTime ] = useState(0);
  // i think you want your intervalId to be a ref so that its value persist thru lifecycles
  const intervalRef = useRef(); 
    
    // things to do when the activePlayer changes
    useEffect(()=>{
      if(activePlayerIndex < 0)
        return
      stopCountDowns();
      // run interval here
      intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
        let activePlayer = players[activePlayerIndex];
        if(activePlayer.timeLeft > 0){
          activePlayer.timeLeft--;
          console.log(activePlayer);
          players[activePlayerIndex] = activePlayer;
          setPlayers(players);
          // update totalTime to trigger flatlist re-render
          setTotalTime(prev=>prev+1)
        }
        else{
          // some notification saying player is out of time?
          setActivePlayerIndex(-1);
        }
      }, 1000)
      return ()=>clearInterval(intervalRef.current)
    },[activePlayerIndex])
   
  const stopCountDowns = () => clearInterval(intervalRef.current)

  const renderItem = ({index,item:{name,timeLeft}})=>{
    return(
      <TouchableOpacity 
        style={[styles.touchable,{ backgroundColor: colors[index]}]} 
        onPress={() => setActivePlayerIndex(index)}
      >
        <Text>{name}</Text>
        <Text>{secondsToMinutes(timeLeft)}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
  // converts seconds to mm:ss form
  const secondsToMinutes = time=>{
    let min = Math.floor(time/60)
    let seconds = time - ( 60 * min )
    return `${min}:${seconds.toString().padStart(2,0)}`
  }
  return(
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={players}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(data,index)=>index}
        extraData={totalActiveTime}
      />
      <View style={styles.wrapper}>
        <Text style={styles.totalTime}>{`Total game time: ${secondsToMinutes(totalActiveTime)}`}</Text>
        <Button
          title="Stop All Timers"
          onPress={stopCountDowns}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  touchable:{
    width: "50%",
    height: 150,
    alignItems: "center", 
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  wrapper:{
    paddingTop:10,
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:'center',
    textAlign:'center'
  },
  totalTime:{
    fontWeight:'700',
    textAlign:'center'
  }
  })
export default TimerScreen;
```